# Update table every two seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm looking to update a table I have every two to three seconds or in real time if possible. I know one way to do this, but when I tried it, it causes the table to constantly flash and it becomes extremely hard to read with it doing that and hurts your eyes. Should I use jQuery and Ajax? How would I implement this without it being very resource heavy and causing the webpage to eventually crash? My table code is below (in table.php):

```
<!-- Table -->

<form action="index.php" method="get" id="dispatch">



         <table>
             <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Incident #</th>
                 <th>Town</th>
                 <th>Location</th>
                 <th>Incident Type</th>
                 <th>Time/Date</th>
                 <th>Admin</th>
                 <th>Delete Entry</th>
            </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             <?php


  if( isset($_POST['town']) )
  {
    $town = $_POST['town'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['location']) )
  {
  $location = $_POST['location'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['incident_type']) )
  {
  $incident_type= $_POST['incident_type'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['time_date']) )
  {
  $time_date= $_POST['time_date'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['admin']) )
  {
  $admin = $_POST['admin'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['id']) )
  {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  }



    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Database error"); 
    mysqli_select_db($db, 'cad');  
    $result= mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `cad` ORDER BY `time_date` DESC LIMIT 20"); 


  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

  $town     = $row['town'];
  $location    = $row['location'];
  $incident_type     = $row['incident_type'];
  $time_date = $row['time_date'];
  $admin    = $row['admin']; 
  $id    = $row['id']; 

echo "


                    <tr>
                        <td class=\"id-center\">
                            ".$id."
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ".$town."
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ".$location."
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ".$incident_type."
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ".$time_date."
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ".$admin."
                        </td>


                        <td>
                        <a href=\"delete.php?id=$id\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this incident?');\" name=\"delete\" value=\"$id\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-default center-1\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></a>
                        </td> 


                        </tr>";
    }

  mysqli_close($db);


  ?>

             </tbody>
             </table> 
             </form>

<!-- End -->
```

Code for my index.php:

```
<!-- Table -->

<div class="col-md-8 column">



     <fieldset>
        <legend>Incident Board (Incidents in red are active)</legend>

         <iframe class="incident-table" src="table.php" name="incident-table" width="100%" height="500px" style="border:0;"></iframe>


    </fieldset>
             </div>

<!-- End -->
```

Comment: Be careful if using Apache for "polling" as you can easily DDOS yourself. Using something like NGINX can be more forgiving or even node.js for the polling part to let you "push" updates instead of pulling them.

Comment: Only update the table if it changes

Answer (score 0):

The best ever way of implementing with a low bandwidth, ofcourse with AJAX is using JSON. Try to fetch a JSON output of all your tabular data and every 2 seconds, fire an AJAX call to get the new data and populate it.

Your AJAX call would be something like this:

```
$.getJSON("path/to/php/json", function (data) {
  $("table").find("#id_of_element").html(data.id_of_element);
});
```

One particular row of your table can be returned like:

```
{
    "Incident": "",
    "Town": "",
    "Location": "",
    "IncidentType": "",
    "Time/Date": "",
    "Admin": "",
    "Delete Entry": ""
}
```

And when this is minified, it would show you:

```
{"Incident":"","Town":"","Location":"","IncidentType":"","Time/Date":"","Admin":"","Delete Entry":""}
```

The server overhead will be really small!

Comment: Thank you. I've never used JSON before so I might need some help on implementing it. Where would I put the AJAX call? I'm assuming in the table.php right? What about the `{
    "Incident": "",
    "Town": "",
    "Location": "",
    "IncidentType": "",
    "Time/Date": "",
    "Admin": "",
    "Delete Entry": ""
}` Where would I put that?

Comment: Can you still help me?

Comment: @huth2349 Yes, I am in the office. Give me a few hours. Is it urgent?

Comment: No it isn't urgent. Just whenever you get time is fine. I just need some help on how to implement you solution into my code and where exactly I should put it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'v been stumped on this issue for a while now. My solutions always cause the page to eventually crash due to too much bandwidth use.